# How to replace formulas into values but with possibilty to remain referenced to its original source (dynamically)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I would like to have the possibility to convert some formula (in my case CONCAT) into values, but with the possibility to select those values and not to have formula shown, and also to be able to change their content on selecting something else in the original cell.

I used:

```
=CONCATENATE(A9;",";B9;",";C9;",";D9;",";E9;",";F9;",";G9;",";H9;",";I12;",";J12;",";K12)
```

Which is fine to have in my format, but then I copied/pasted as Paste Special - Values, and from that, I did drop down so I can have referenced.

is there any other way but without macro?

[File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezfio.gif)

**EDIT!

Better explanation, all in the picture down!**

[File 2 - update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBEjz.gif)

Comment: Hi @Mirza,, you mean to say that while converting Formula into Value, you want to get the Formula itself or the Value only for example `=Concatenate(A1,B1)` if returns `US100`. Then U want only `US100` in cell or the formula `=Concatenate(A1,B1)`. Since you have written,, **but with possibilty to remain referenced to its original source** !!

Comment: @RajeshS I want to get value, but to be still referenced to formula, because the field are dropdowns and it is always changeable. But I need them in the "line" so I can copy whole or part that I need to quickly, instead of looking and searching.

Comment: ,, you may try Formula Auditing,,, Precedents/Dependence,, coz either you convert Formula in to Value or get the Formula only (has cell references) also.

Comment: @RajeshS Thx for the tip but still I am finding references to drop-down list easier...it takes a bit more space but better than nothing. :/

Comment: If possible share the workbook on cloud/ Drop box to examine, the attaches screen shot is not enough to understand !!

Comment: @RajeshS Check now post, I cant simply send workbook but I provide all infos now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108787/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-mirza).